# How can I prepend a 0 to the beginning of single-figure inch values?

Tags: r

I have a list of height values in feet and inches that looks something like this:

```
"5' 4" 
"5' 11"
"5' 10"
"5' 7"
"6' 0"
"6' 3" 
"5' 8" 
"6' 2" 
"5' 9"
```

I want to be able to prepend a `0` to those heights whose `inch` value is a single figure.

**Also note that I don't want to convert the values into another metric; I want the format to remain as shown in the example above.**

As such, the example above would ideally look like this:

```
"5' 04" 
"5' 11"
"5' 10"
"5' 07"
"6' 00"
```

The reason is so that when I plot the values, this doesn't happen (notice, for example, how the heights `6' 10"` and `6' 11"` come straight after `6' 1"`):

[image: The heights are not in order]

How can I achieve this?

A sample of my `height` object:

```
structure(c(9L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 15L, 20L, 13L, 19L, 1L, 14L), .Label = c("", 
"4' 11\"", "5' 0\"", "5' 1\"", "5' 10\"", "5' 11\"", "5' 2\"", 
"5' 3\"", "5' 4\"", "5' 5\"", "5' 6\"", "5' 7\"", "5' 8\"", "5' 9\"", 
"6' 0\"", "6' 1\"", "6' 10\"", "6' 11\"", "6' 2\"", "6' 3\"", 
"6' 4\"", "6' 5\"", "6' 6\"", "6' 7\"", "6' 8\"", "6' 9\"", "7' 2\"", 
"7' 5\""), class = "factor")
```

Comment: @SteveM I highlighted the fact that I didn't want to do this (literally in bold) in my question.

Comment: Is your raw data in ```6' 5"``` format? Or did you paste together two fields into one?

Comment: @Cole Already in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match capture the digit (`\\d`) followed by the double quote (`"`) at the end (`$`) of each element which follows a space, and replace with a space, 0 and the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
sub('\\s(\\d)"$', ' 0\\1"', str1)
#[1] "5' 04\"" "5' 11\"" "5' 10\"" "5' 07\"" "6' 00\"" "6' 03\"" "5' 08\"" "6' 02\"" ""        "5' 09\""
```

---

Or another option is to read with `read.table/read.csv` into two columns and use `sprintf` to get the required format

```
do.call(sprintf, c(read.table(text = as.character(str1),
   header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         comment.char = '"'), fmt = c('%s %02d"')))
#[1] "5' 04\"" "5' 11\"" "5' 10\"" "5' 07\"" "6' 00\"" "6' 03\"" "5' 08\"" "6' 02\"" "5' 09\""
```